# Check project path in custom Visual Studio wizard

Tags: visual-studio-2010, project-template

I have created a custom template wizard for Visual Studio 2010. Thus I'm implementing the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TemplateWizard.IWizard` interface. I want projects generated by this wizard to always be placed in a certain directory. If the user selected another directory a message box would show the error *"Blah projects must be placed in C:\Blah"*.

**Q:** Before the wizard is shown, is it possible to check the project's destination directory?